# python combine array item by item

Tags: python, arrays

if i have three arrays the first one is **A,B,C,D** and the second one is **E,F,G,H**
and the last one is **I,J,K,L**
i want to use this three array and make an output like this :

```
AEI
BFJ
CGK
DHL
```

i try this code

```
import re
array1 = 'A','B','C','D'
array2 = 'E','F','G','H'
array3 = 'I','J','K','L'
arys = [array1,array2,array3]

for a,b,c,d in arys:
    print a+b+c+d
```

it didnt work

how to make this work

Comment: `tuple != array`. What you are creating is a list of tuples. Tuples function very similarly to lists however they are immutable, which can be a subtle but important distinction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
array1 = 'A','B','C','D'
array2 = 'E','F','G','H'
array3 = 'I','J','K','L'
for elems in zip(array1, array2, array3):
    print ''.join(elems)
```

It prints

```
AEI
BFJ
CGK
DHL
```

*Edit*: you could also just zip the 3 strings together instead of creating tuples and get the same output:

```
for elems in zip("ABCD", "EFGH", "IJKL"):
    print(''.join(elems))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with map in python2:

```
array1 = 'A','B','C','D'
array2 = 'E','F','G','H'
array3 = 'I','J','K','L'
print("\n".join(map("".join, map(None, array1, array2, array3))))
AEI
BFJ
CGK
DHL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way (you definitely want to use zip() here):

```
array1 = 'A','B','C','D'
array2 = 'E','F','G','H'
array3 = 'I','J','K','L'

for triplet in zip(array1, array2, array3):
    print ''.join(triplet)
```